# Max value of max_input_vars

Tags: php

We're using some assessments platform and we need to export results for further processing.

Platform allows export tests' results to CSV format. Problem is that it requires high `max_input_vars`. Current value is 1000 (in `php.ini`) and we need a lot higher.

So I was wondering how high I can make `max_input_vars`. We're running platform on closed network, so security is not highest priority, but we need to avoid data loss or corruption.

What is max `max_input_vars` value or what maximum is recommended?

Comment: What does `max_input_vars` have to do with exporting? Are you passing values to the server which then get reformatted to CSV and dumped back out?

Comment: I don't know,  we're not developing it (it's open source project TAO TESTING). But yeah, it seems that it's working in some strange ways.

Comment: This platform is already chosen to be used, so it's pretty late to change the route. Getting results in CSV would be convenient, so that's why I'm asking this question. I want to know the limits of how much data I can expect to export.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) it is an INT. If you're on a 64 bit system, the max value of php ints (signed) is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. On 32 bits it's 2,147,483,648.

Comment: Is there any danger of using very high values of this ?

Comment: @SoulJam On a closed network, not really. Just make sure no-one actually sends 9 sextillion inputs at it. This limit is typically a measure to avoid types of ddos attacks.

Comment: I hope high values don't increase chances of dataloss too much. Thanks for answer :) somebody downvoted, so can't even vote up :/ Answer accepeted.

Comment: @SoulJam there shouldn't be any chance of dataloss